# Install Japanese in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, internationalization, input-language, japanese

I study Japanese so it's helpful to be able to type it on my computer.

I have iBus installed and under Local in Settings, I installed Japanese, though it only gave me the option for translations. I went into iBus and tried to add Japanese, the option was there but can't be selected.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is ibus running?

Answer (score 1):

Ibus needs additional packages to work with japanese, I found it working only after installing ibus-anthy and then adding Japanese in the iBus settings. See if this helps.